# как реализовать перетаскивание

Tags: android

У меня есть 2-Button, и 1-Textview. Теперь когда нажимаю на Первый Button и удерживая перетаскиваю на Второй Button и когда в Приделах 2го Button вошел придел квадрата 1гоButton то в Textview пишется AB. Как это сделать правильно?

[image: Проект]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements    View.OnTouchListener {

Button btn, btn2;
TextView txw;
String dates;
int slide = 100;
float x;
float y;

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
txw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txw);

btn.setOnTouchListener(this);
btn2.setOnTouchListener(this);
txw.setOnTouchListener(this);
}


@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
x = motionEvent.getX();
y = motionEvent.getY();
float ex = btn2.getX();
float ey = btn2.getY();

switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
         dates = (String) btn.getText();
        Log.e(TAG, "onTouch: DAtes = =" + dates );
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // движение
        if (x >= ex && x <= ex && y >= ey && y <= ey ){

            dates = dates+btn2.getText();
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // отпускание

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

        break;
}
txw.setText(dates);
return true;
}
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5xk9yzFMsw

Comment: вот ссылка на видео ... но там кнопка лежит не на своем месте.... и когда А удерживаю и перетаскиваю на B то .... то добавляется бесконечно

Comment: первое что сразу бросается в глаза - это координаты кнопки. getX и getY - это координаты верхнего левого угла.

Comment: извините, у вас убойственные навзание переменных. Я уверен, если вы перепишете код с нормальными иксами и игриками, вы сами увидите промах алгоритма. пока же в этом ничего понять нельзя, кроме того что оно не верно работает)